What is a "re-simulation"?
In the context of galaxy formation and evolution simulations, what is a re-simulation and how is it different from a simulation?

Where did you see the word written?  Does "another simulation" make sense in context? Needs detail

I read it in an article and it was used as a noun with little detail about the method. It's not my area, so I didn't know if it referred to a specific way of simulating a DM halo.

Which article?  you should link to the article so we can see the context.  Or at very least give a proper citation so someone could check it out.

"re-doing the simulation" with different parameters, for example more detailed resolution in space or time, or focussing on a small area.

One of the particularity of the HORIZON 3 project is that it allows the re-simulation of some areas of interest for astronomers. For example in Figure 3, a supercluster of galaxies has been chosen to be re-simulated at a higher resolution (highest number of particules) taking the initial information and the boundary conditions from the larger box (of lower resolution) (source)

The simulation in a smaller area can be redone at greater detail using the first simulation as a starting point.
